# Detect when application is started via NFC in ICS

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

ICS introduces the possibility to share an application via Android Beam using NFC, and as far as I understood if an app is opened on deviceA it will automatically be started on deviceB (if it's already installed on it, otherwise the Market app will open) when the devices are close enough and a user "touches to beam" it. Is there a way, inside the launcher Activity, to detect if it has been started because of a NFC message or because of a user interaction?

Comment: Sorry for the laziness today. But http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html is a great resource. The gist of it is, you will get a different intent, so check for the NFC tag action.

Comment: I read that but it didn't help (or I'm REALLY missing something here). The "you will get a different intent" bit of you comment is not true, I debugged my app when it's started via NFC: the action is `android.intent.action.MAIN` and the category is `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`, so the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

Only NFC Intents are started when a beam occurs. These are ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED, or ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED. Check out the beaming section of the dev guide for how to handle beams: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#p2p

Answer (score 0):

In case the Android Beam (or NDEF) message contains an Android Application Record, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#aar, the resulting Intent to start the app will not be of the action ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, but ACTION_MAIN. This method can be used to launch *any* app, including apps that do not filter for NFC intents.

Comment: so how do we know that it has been started with an NFC Beam? @nfc-guy

Comment: Yeah..but when using AAR, the intent is ACTION_MAIN..which cannot be distinguished from Beam events...

Comment: You should make the AAR the last (or at least not the first) record and add an intent filter for the first record.