# NFC tag - why use AAR and LaunchApp rather than URL intent with Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

Given that you can launch an installed android app using an NFC tag with a URL on it, using, e.g.:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="http://myurl.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/something" />
```

And that you can make that shorter using a url shortening service, or your own domain, and that redirects to the play store, why would you use an AAR on a tag? (Also, I believe the AAR intent wont pass data to the app).

I'm looking to make a tag that supports multiple OS, with as few bytes as possible - if I create a website that has links to each phone's store, what advantage is there to including an AAR or LaunchApp record on the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why would you use an AAR on a tag?

Because your (original, pre-edit) proposed URL would cause the tag to *always* go to the Play Store. An AAR is designed to *only* go to the Play Store *if* there are no apps on the device that can handle the primary NFC record. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887275/aar-record-in-nfc-wheres-the-payload) to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887275/aar-record-in-nfc-wheres-the-payload) for more on this.

Your approach of using `http://myurl.com/something` should work fine, so long as:

- The tag is only supposed to be valid for your app
- Nothing else on the device advertises support for that specific host and path prefix

Comment: My example url probably wasnt the best. I've eddited my question.

If it was www.myurl.com, and that redirected to the play store;
-if the app isnt installed, it will redirect 
-if it is, the intent will fire. 

I'd read your answer to your question before posting mine - yours looks like it need a URI or MIME message and an AAR - which is too large.

Comment: Thanks for the updated reply. 
I didn't like editing the question and making your answer not-relevant, but wasn't sure of the procedure / etiquette.